# Internet Explorer 7,8 Font Face with Turkish Chars

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

I am trying to use [Open Sans (Turkish version)](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans)

I am pretty sure i applied correct syntax. however Turkish character looks different in IE 7,8

**IE 9**

[image: Ie 9 semibold font]

[image: Ie 9 regular font]

**IE8 and IE7**

[image: Ie 8 semibold font]

[image: Ie 8 regular font]

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'open_sansregular';
src: url('Fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('Fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanssemibold';
    src: url('Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

**EDIT**
This is strange I uploaded example [here](http://test.ardaterekeci.com) and it works perfectly. Problem still exist on localhost

I am using VS 2013 and IIS Express 8.0

Comment: Sometimes the issue relies in how the browser reads the font. This being said, there is often very little difference. To be sure, can you show your charset, a sample page, etc.?

Comment: I will add sample page when I am at home. It looks really weird when I use small font size

Comment: I would also suggest you try [Google Font's version of Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans) and see if the issue lies in your font or how the browser parses it.

Comment: The title refers to IE 7 and 8, the samples are said to be from IE 8 and IE 9, and there is no *apparent* difference between them. On a very close look, I might say that the lowercase text has somewhat decreased spacing. The odds are that you have generated the font files so that Turkish letters are omitted, but there is no way make sure of this from the information provided.

Comment: @Publi I tried Google Webfonts as you know i cant use numbers on font-weight property on IE8 thats why i need custom fonts.

Comment: It maybe a slight difference in Cleartype, those are VERY similar glyphs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I dont think so. There is difference between link that i gave and localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

1. download fonts from font-squirrel
2. Upload them to font-squirrel's Font-Generalor
3. Check Keep existing in Trutype Hinting Section

[image: Font-Squirrel]